# Bootstrap navbar menu integrated in WordPress issue

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have recently started learning how to use WordPress, and I have selected a simple theme and want to implement the bootstrap navbar fixed-top menu.

I have so far succeed, and have the menu working when the screen is in full mode, and loads in the correct primary menu.

However, I need help with a couple things.

- Firstly, I have the navbar set so when you hover over a Dropdown, it auto dropdowns the sub menu, but I would like the parent link to be clickable to it's relevant page also
- In standard `HTML` & `CSS`, this is simple to do, but in WordPress, when you load in the menu I find it a bit more complex.

Here is how I have input the navbar within the `header.php` file:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <?php
    // Fix menu overlap bug..
    if ( is_admin_bar_showing() ) echo '<div style="min-height: 28px;"></div>';
    ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?></a>
        </div>
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'              => 'primary-menu',
            'theme_location'    => 'primary-menu',
            'depth'             => 2,
            'container'         => 'div',
            'container_class'   => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
            'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
            );
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see that the primary menu is loaded in with some PHP. The issue with this is, it does not allow for me to change the `a class=""` on a Link so I can input `disable`, so it can be clicked as a Link.

Also the Link is currently '#' which I cannot change.

Lastly, when I resize my browser to check if the menu is responsive, when the toggle button displays, I click that and it shows the links, once I hover over the link with a sub menu it again auto drops down (which is not what I want when the responsive toggle menu is displayed). I want to click the link when the menu is shrunk down, rather than auto dropdown on full view.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do :/ Please edit your question to make it clearer what your trying to achieve. See [ask] to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the Parent Link clickable you need to edit the `wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php`.

I have done this before by editing some lines within the `wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php`file and here's how.

**First fine this line of code:**

```
$atts = array();
$atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->title )   ? $item->title  : '';
$atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )  ? $item->target : '';
$atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )     ? $item->xfn    : '';
// If item has_children add atts to a.
if ( $args->has_children && $depth === 0 ) {
    $atts['href']           = '#';
    $atts['data-toggle']    = 'dropdown';
  $atts['class']          = 'dropdown-toggle';
    $atts['aria-haspopup']  = 'true';
} else {
    $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
}
```

These lines of code are normally around `line 78` to `line 91` what you can do is replace all of the lines above with these lines of code:

```
$atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->title )   ? $item->title  : '';
$atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )  ? $item->target : '';
$atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )     ? $item->xfn    : '';
// If item has_children add atts to a.
// if ( $args->has_children && $depth === 0 ) {
if ( $args->has_children ) {
    $atts['href'] = $item->url;
    $atts['data-toggle']    = 'dropdown';
    $atts['class']          = 'dropdown-toggle';
} else {
    $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
}
```

What I have done here is I have changed the parent link to print its own link instead of replacing it with a `#`

```
$atts['href'] = $item->url;
```

Instead of the original which was to change the parent link to a `#`

```
$atts['href'] = '#';
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the link has changed from # to it's relevant URL, only issue is now the Link does not click at all. The menu still drops down automatically, but when you click the Parent link it does nothing.

Comment: Ok, I sussed it by adding disabled next to the 'dropdown-toggle' class... issue I am having now though, is when the browser is shrunk down and the toggle is menu button is displayed, when you click that the menu comes down, the Parent links still display the Dropdown automatically, rather than clicking on it (which is how it should be).

Comment: I am sure this is just some CSS that you have added to make the dropdown hover that is going to be used across all devices. Best option - where you CSS is for making it hover put that into `media (min-width: 992px)` that why it will only apply to screens above 992px

Comment: Ok, I sussed that part, thank you... last issue and then it should be sorted, Adding Disabled to the class with dropdown-toggle, means that even when the browser is shrunk and the toggle menu is display, if you click on the Parent link, it takes you to that page rather than display the Dropdown menu.

Comment: Yeah there is really no work around for that - best option here is to on mobile always display the list of dropdowns just for the mobile

Comment: That's a pity... was almost completed! :) Can't win them all... how do you set the dropdowns to display on mobile?

Comment: You can use `@media (max-width: 767px)` and then select the class of the dropdown and then give it `display: block`